# Where is the NFS volume located on a kubernetes Node?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

I've been using https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/README.md as a guide.

I've successfully set the above working. However I'm not able to locate where the actual "NFS Volume" is located at - I'm guessing it's just an ordinary directory.

I have two goals here:

- To prepopulate the volume / directory initially
- To make a backup of this volume / directory

**nfs-pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Mi
```

Answer (score 2):

This deployment is GCE specific NFS. NFS server run as POD in the cluster `image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8`

looks at this deployment file https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/nfs-server-rc.yaml

This pod acts as NFS server. if you run `kubectl get pods' you will see nfs-server pod is running.

`volume-nfs:` is google image, not familer with all the features. I can see the `kubectl cp` option to copy the file to and from the NFS server POD.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.7/#cp

eg:

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/nfs-server:/exports
```

The above command will only work if the `tar` executable is present on the container.

Comment: I don't understand the answer.

Comment: I still do not understand how this helps me solve 1. backup of the directory 2. prepopulating this directory

I ideally just need to know the how to determine the path on the node.

Comment: added the example option to transfer the file to and from the nfs-server pod.